# Last piece to solve reordering UITableView backed with Core Data puzzle

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, uitableview

I'm trying to reorder UITableView in iOS application.
After harvesting a lot of StackOverFlow questions, I used this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath {
    self.userDrivenDataModelChange = YES;

    NSUInteger fromIndex = fromIndexPath.row;  
    NSUInteger toIndex = toIndexPath.row;

    NSManagedObject *affectedObject = [self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:fromIndex];  
    [affectedObject setValue: [NSNumber numberWithInt:toIndex] forKey:@"priority"];

    NSUInteger start, end;
    int delta;

    if (fromIndex < toIndex) {
        // move was down, need to shift up
        delta = -1;
        start = fromIndex + 1;
        end = toIndex;
    } else { // fromIndex > toIndex
        // move was up, need to shift down
        delta = 1;
        start = toIndex;
        end = fromIndex - 1;
    }

    for (NSUInteger i = start; i <= end; i++) {
        NSManagedObject *otherObject = [self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:i];  
        NSNumber *oldPriority = (NSNumber *)[otherObject valueForKey:@"priority"];
        int tmp = [oldPriority intValue] + delta;
        NSNumber *newPriority = [NSNumber numberWithInt:tmp];
        [otherObject setValue: [NSNumber numberWithInt:[newPriority intValue]] forKey:@"priority"];        
    }


    NSError *error = nil;
    if (! [self.fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    // Should I call something here?

    self.userDrivenDataModelChange = NO;
}
```

After sending save message to the context object, What should I call? some method on the fetch controller or the table view?  because it is not working in the current shape.

Should I send save to the context object in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're already sending save message to managedObjectContext, which is fine, `if (! [self.fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext save:&error])`.

To see updated results in table view, it'll be probably sufficient to call `[tableView reloadData];` at the end of this method.

Comment: This seems like it updates the display data of the individual cells but not the order, has anyone managed to get this approach to work?

Answer (score 0):

You should also check if both from and to index paths are equal, if they are it'll crash!

```
if([toIndexPath isEqual:fromIndexPath]) return;
```

Answer (score 0):

// THE ABOVE ANSWER IS CORRECT. HERE WOULD BE ANOTHER PROPERLY-WORKING EXAMPLE WITH MY OWN OBJECT NAMES

## pragma mark - Re-Ordering

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  return indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row < self.list.sortedTasks.count;
  }
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath {

  NSInteger fromIndex = sourceIndexPath.row;
  NSInteger toIndex = destinationIndexPath.row;

  Task *movingTask = [self.list.sortedTasks objectAtIndex:sourceIndexPath.row];
  Task *destinationTask = [self.list.sortedTasks objectAtIndex:destinationIndexPath.row];

  NSArray *tempList = self.list.sortedTasks;

  if (fromIndex == toIndex) {
      return;
  }

  // Move the active task to the destination task's position.
  movingTask.order = destinationTask.order;
  NSLog(@"moving %@ to %@", movingTask.details, movingTask.order);

  NSUInteger start, end;
  int order;

  if (fromIndex < toIndex) {
      // move was down, need to shift up
      order = -1;
      start = fromIndex + 1;
      end = toIndex;
  } else { // fromIndex > toIndex
      // move was up, need to shift down
      order = 1;
      start = toIndex;
      end = fromIndex - 1;
  }

  for (
      NSUInteger i = start; i <= end; i++) {
      Task *otherObject = [tempList objectAtIndex:i];
      NSNumber *oldPriority = otherObject.order;
      int tmp = [oldPriority intValue] + order;
      NSNumber *newPriority = [NSNumber numberWithInt:tmp];
      otherObject.order = newPriority;

  ```
  NSLog(@"moving %@ to %@", otherObject.details, otherObject.order);
  ```

  }

  [self.managedObjectContext save:nil];

}